# powershell excel get first row(header) column count

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm trying to count the cell number of the first row (A1-D1) which is known as header and get that count as the counter.

As all the while find most of them using `Usedrange` to count the columns:

```
$headercolcount=($worksheet.UsedRange.Columns).count
```

But `UsedRange` will capture maximum count in the whole activesheet, which resulting not identical to the column count in first row if there is extra content data below the header.

I only wish to grab just the first row:

[[image: Sample excel view]]

Update:
For clearer view, here is an example.
As 1F & 1G there are no value present, so the answer should be 5 as 1A-1E as it contains data. So how should I grab the 5 correctly?

[[image]]

Comment: Not familiar with PowerShell but you want something like `$headercolcount = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count`  The `UsedRange` is always a rectangular area though, so `$worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count` would be equivalent

Comment: yea that what i meaning, i also tried as you proposed $headercolcount = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count before and it's not working too, it will not counting the column, it resulting in counting the characters i think so as it resulting in large value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Get-Process excel | Stop-Process -Force
# Specify the path to the Excel file and the WorkSheet Name
$FilePath = "C:\temp\A_A.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Blad1" # In english this is probably Sheet1
# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
# Open Excel file and in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
# Load WorkSheet 'Blad 1' in variable Worksheet
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$xlup = -4162
$lastRow = $WorkSheet.cells.Range("A1048576").End($xlup).row

# get the highest amount of columns
$colMax = ($WorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns).count
# initiatie a counter
$count = $null
# set the column you'd like to count
$row = 1

for ($i = 0; $i -le $colMax; $i++){
    if($worksheet.rows.Item("$row").columns.Item($i+1).text){
        $count++
    }    
}

$count
```

This should work. It takes the highest amount of columns. It then loops until it reaches that amount. During the loop it checks if the cell on that row is filled or not, if it is, it adds to the counter.

If you have millions of lines, this might not be the best way but this works for me.

I've testes it with an excel file:

[image]

With

```
$row = 1 this will give : 5
$row = 2 this will give : 6
$row = 3 this will give : 7
$row = 4 this will give : 8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Specify the path to the Excel file and the WorkSheet Name
$FilePath = "C:\temp\A_A.xlsx"
$SheetName = "Blad1" # In english this is probably Sheet1
# Create an Object Excel.Application using Com interface
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# Disable the 'visible' property so the document won't open in excel
$objExcel.Visible = $false
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $false
# Open Excel file and in $WorkBook
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
# Load WorkSheet 'Blad 1' in variable Worksheet
$WorkSheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item($SheetName)
$xlup = -4162
$lastRow = $WorkSheet.cells.Range("A1048576").End($xlup).row
$amountofcolumns = $worksheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Columns.Count   
#OUTPUT
write-host "Last Used row:" $lastRow 
Write-host "Amount of columns" $amountofcolumns
#show all columnnames
for($i =  1 ; $i -le $amountofcolumns; $i++){
    $worksheet.Cells.Item(1,$i).text
}
```

This will show you how many rows you have AND will show you all values in the first row , ergo your titles.

Comment: Not working, still unable to capture first row number of column that containing the data.

Comment: Yeah so "not working" -> not very informative.
Did you change the $Sheetname into English format? Or in your language if you have Excel in another language.

Comment: Yes, I did named it to Book1. I tried and run your code against the above updated example excel file. The first row that containing data are 5. However your code shows amount of columns = 6 as the code count until 1F i think so.
Sorry if there is any poor explanations.
Here is result:
`write-host "Last Used row:" $lastRow`
Last Used row: 4
`Write-host "Amount of columns" $amountofcolumns`
Amount of columns 6
`for($i =  1 ; $i -le $amountofcolumns; $i++){
$worksheet.Cells.Item(1,$i).text
}`
s
sd
dssd
dsdsd
21321

Comment: As I mentioned above, UsedRange is *always a regular rectange* - it will enclose all of the data on the sheet, and extends to the right as far as the right-most entry on any row.  It doesn't have different number of columns per row